# Why is x = x + 100 treated differently than x += 100 that compiles to the same IL?

Tags: c#, casting

We know that these two addition statements are equivalent and compile to the same IL code:

```
int x = 100;

x += 100;
x = x + 100;
```

However, when there is an explicit cast required I have noticed something strange:

```
byte b = 100;

b += 200; // Compiles (1)
b = b + 200; // Cannot implicitly convert int to byte (2)
b = (byte) (b + 200); // Compiles (3)
```

It is obvious why the second statement requires an explicit cast because the result of the addition is an integer. But the weird thing to me is the first statement. It compiles to the exact same IL as the third statement, so it looks like compiler adds a cast that is supposed to be explicit, for us. But it can't do it in the second statement.

It seems contradictory to me because I would expect the first statement to be equivalent to the second and never compile, so why does it compile?

Note: This doesn't compile when an explicit cast is required from `long` to `int`:

```
int x = 100;
long y = 200;

x += y;
```

Comment: The operand += has a built in cast to type on the left side of the equation.  The plus sign by itself is used to combine different types so you must manually add a cast.

Comment: @jdweng then why `int += long` doesn't compile?

Comment: For your long example `x += 200L` would be a better example because if you do `byte x = 100; int y = 200; x += y;` it does not compile either.

Comment: An int is 32 bits and a long is 64.  You can't shove 64 bits into 32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really need to go to the [specs](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) for this sort of information (and it can be really hard to get your head around the wording). However, straight from the horses mouth

> **12.18.3 Compound assignment**
>
> An operation of the form `x op= y` is processed by applying binary
>   operator overload resolution (§12.4.5) as if the operation was written
>   `x op y.` Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of `x`, the operation is evaluated as `x = x
>     op y`, except that x is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the
>     type of `x` , and if `y` is implicitly convertible to the type of `x`
>     or the operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated
>     as `x = (T)(x op y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that `x` is
>     evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, the compound assignment is invalid, and a binding-time error occurs.
>
> ...
>
> *blah blah blah*
>
> ...
>
> The second rule above permits `x op= y` to be evaluated as `x = (T)(x op y)` **in certain contexts**. The rule exists such that the predefined operators **can be used as compound operators when the left operand is
>   of type `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, or `char`**. Even when both
>   arguments are of one of those types, the predefined operators produce
>   a result of type int, as described in §12.4.7.3. **Thus, without a cast
>   it would not be possible to assign the result to the left operand**.
>
> The intuitive effect of the rule for predefined operators **is simply
>   that `x op= y` is permitted if both of `x op y` and `x = y` are
>   permitted**.
>
> ```
> byte b = 0;
> char ch = '\0';
> int i = 0;
> b += 1; // Ok
> b += 1000; // Error, b = 1000 not permitted
> b += i; // Error, b = i not permitted
> b += (byte)i; // Ok
> ch += 1; // Error, ch = 1 not permitted
> ch += (char)1; // Ok
> ```
>
> the intuitive reason for each error is that a corresponding simple
>   assignment would also have been an error.

In short, computer says no.

Comment: Surprisingly though, `b += 200` does **not** compile in VB! _(when `Option Strict On`, of course)_

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yeah different specs, these are C# specs of course, there is a whole other world of vb.net specs

Comment: So looks like the compiler still _tries_ to make sure the conversion is safe before emitting a cast there, by enforcing `x = y` should be permitted. although in my example `b += 200` compiles but still causes overflow because `b`'s initial value was 100.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah, I'm aware of that. I was just surprised because VB is usually the "less strict" one.

Comment: "_The rule exists such that the predefined operators can be used as compound operators when the left operand is of type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char_"

does spec say this anywhere, specifying these types only?

Comment: @SelmanGenç  You can dig through this a little more, there are other relevant parts that left out for brevity http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf

Comment: @TheGeneral would be nice if you format quoted sections as quote in your answer. I thought those were your words :)

Comment: @SelmanGenç hahah you are right, sorry not intentional. thanks for the edit